# How can I refer to a non-fixed position in vector - R:Purrr?

Tags: r, purrr

I have two lists of vectors:

- `list_1` contains five vectors each of equal length of 5 containing strings
- `list_2` contains five vectors each of equal length of 2 containing integers

```
list_1 <- list(
   c("red","blue","blue","red","blue"),
   c("green","green","green","red","red"),
   c("blue","green","blue","red","red"),
   c("green","green","red","red","red"),
   c("red","blue","blue","red","green")) %>% 
       set_names(c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005))

list_2 <- list(
  c(2,4),
  c(1,5),
  c(3,1),
  c(4,5),
  c(4,4)
) %>% set_names(c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005))
```

I'd like to use `map`for each vector (1001, 1002,...) in `list_2` match a string from `list_1` from a position matching the respective integer. Output would look like this:

```
List of 5
 $ 1001: chr [1:2] "blue" "red"
 $ 1002: chr [1:2] "green" "red"
 $ 1003: chr [1:2] "blue" "blue"
 $ 1004: chr [1:2] "red" "red"
 $ 1005: chr [1:2] "red" "red"
```

**It is simple if a position, we recall is a fixed value `map(list_1, .x[[some value]]`, but how to do that for a variable position?**

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `map2`, to iterate over two lists, one pair of elements at a time. The bit to be careful about is if your lists aren't the same names or in the same order or the same length. If you can satisfy those conditions, then it's straightforward indexing of `.x[.y]`, where `.x` is the first list's element, and `.y` is the second list's element.

```r
library(purrr)
list_1 <- list(
  c("red","blue","blue","red","blue"),
  c("green","green","green","red","red"),
  c("blue","green","blue","red","red"),
  c("green","green","red","red","red"),
  c("red","blue","blue","red","green")) %>% 
  set_names(c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005))

list_2 <- list(
  c(2,4),
  c(1,5),
  c(3,1),
  c(4,5),
  c(4,4)
) %>% set_names(c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005))
```

```r
# If you can guarantee the two lists are in order with respect to each other
map2(
  list_1, list_2,
  ~.x[.y]
)
#> $`1001`
#> [1] "blue" "red" 
#> 
#> $`1002`
#> [1] "green" "red"  
#> 
#> $`1003`
#> [1] "blue" "blue"
#> 
#> $`1004`
#> [1] "red" "red"
#> 
#> $`1005`
#> [1] "red" "red"
```

```r
# Otherwise:
ord <- names(list_1)
if (length(list_1) != length(list_2[ord])) { stop("Mismatched lengths and names!") }

map2(
  list_1, list_2[ord],
  ~.x[.y]
)
#> $`1001`
#> [1] "blue" "red" 
#> 
#> $`1002`
#> [1] "green" "red"  
#> 
#> $`1003`
#> [1] "blue" "blue"
#> 
#> $`1004`
#> [1] "red" "red"
#> 
#> $`1005`
#> [1] "red" "red"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>